# PHP output to browser is rendered as text and adds numbers in the code when using flush()

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, flush

I have the same code running on various servers, and on only one of them under very specific circumstances that I haven't quite figured out yet, my code fails with a really spectacular issue.

Here's what I'm doing:

I have a processing script that usually takes a few minutes to run, so I start with the following code:

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
ob_implicit_flush(1);

$str = <<< STR
<html><head><title>Line Processing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="progressAnim" style="height: 20px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: 4px 0 0 4px; background-color: #EEE;">
    <img src="/images/formatting/progress_16x16_grey_01.gif" width="16" height="16" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 2px;" />
    <span style="margin-top: 4px;">Page load in progress - please wait...</span>
</div>
<div id="status_time_elapsed" class="status"></div>
<div id="status_percentage" class="status"></div>
<div id="status_saved" class="status"></div>
<div id="status_current" class="status"></div>
<style type="text/css">
[... styles here ...]
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateStatus(curStatus, savStatus, time_elapsed, percentage)
{
    if (percentage != '')
    {
        d('status_percentage').innerHTML = "Estimated overall completion: " + percentage + "% completed.";
    }
    if (savStatus != '')
    {
        d('status_saved').innerHTML += savStatus;
        if (savStatus.indexOf('<div') < 0) d('status_saved').innerHTML += '<br />';
    }
    d('status_current').innerHTML = curStatus;
    d('status_time_elapsed').innerHTML = "Time elapsed since the import started: " + time_elapsed;
}

function d(div)
{
    return document.getElementById(div);
}
</script>
STR;
echo $str;
```

Then, as the script processes, every 100 records I call a PHP function that outputs data to the screen that JavaScript then parses for me:

```
function UpdateLineProcessStatus($curStatus = '', $savStatus = '', $percentage = '', $time_elapsed = '')
{
    global $isRunByUser, $starttime;

    if (!$isRunByUser)
        return;

    $str = <<< STR
<script type="text/javascript">
UpdateStatus('$curStatus', '$savStatus', '$time_elapsed', '$percentage');
</script>
STR;
    echo $str;
    flush();
}
```

So basically, this sends the JavaScript code `UpdateStatus()` to the screen which handles everything else.

This same script has worked for me in various projects on multiple servers.

Here is what happens in this one situation:

The code outputs the HTML header and keeps sending `UpdateStatus()` as it should, but at some point in the script things change.

First off, the browser doesn't parse the HTML or JavaScript but instead displays all the code as text.

Second, the next `UpdateStatus()` output happens at the TOP of the screen, not at the bottom. Then it continues where it left off at the bottom.

Third, after every `UpdateStatus()` call after the first irregular one, a number is added, e.g. 90 or 8f or 120 or 14b or 23a. At first I thought it was hex numbers, but then I found the 3 digit ones, and there's a 4 digit one, too - maybe some kind of checksum...?

Example:

```
6d
<script type="text/javascript">
    UpdateStatus('Reading client 801 of 1189...', '', '00:15', '');
</script>
```

And fourth, the server header is also displayed in plain text...

So to be clear: The output that is actually on screen starts like this:

```
8f
<script type="text/javascript">
    UpdateStatus('Reading transaction 9601 of 16263...', '', '00:03', '');
</script>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 18:16:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Linux/SUSE)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=72
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

5deb
<html><head><title>Line Processing</title>
```

Then we have normal output of the rest of the header and then all the normal JavaScript lines until we reach output `Reading transaction 9501 of 12264`. Then the next line is "missing" (i.e. moved to the top of the page), and then it continues with `9701` and starts adding the numbers at the beginning or end of the code.

So not only does it render all HTML code (plus the http headers) as text and adds numbers, it also added that line at the top of the output as opposed to in between which is probably the biggest mystery to me since I am sending every bit of information to the screen immediately using `echo`.

My script completes successfully, sends the HTML closing tags and stuff with one last number `0` added, done.

This happens on Firefox on Windows XP - I don't have more information on this yet, but I do know that this version of Firefox has a menu (which by default is now turned off) and does NOT have any of the new menu buttons (the orange Firefox button or the three line button), so maybe it's just an outdated version of Firefox. However, on the same browser, most of the time the script works just fine. It's just under very mysterious circumstances that this issue occurs.

The web server is either at the client location or somewhere nearby and connected through a VPN connection - I don't have that information at this time. But still, most of the time, the script works fine, and I haven't figured out yet when it does this.

Frankly, I don't even know where to start here...

I am guessing it could be a virus or a malicious Firefox extension, and I'll pass this on to the client to check into, but what else could this be?

If it was a PHP error, I wouldn't expect it to send a 2-3 digit code on screen...

Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like a “hiccup” … if this happens only in one specific browser (and even on just one specific machine?), but works fine “everywhere” else – then it could either be a browser bug in processing long-time continuous input streams, or it gets mangled up somewhere “on the line”, meaning somewhere in the network in between client and server … but with so little information, it is hard to speculate even.

Comment: As for where to even start to investigate this, I’d suggest using a tool/extension of some sort on the machine where this happens that is able to log every bit (well, rather byte) of received data, response headers _and_ body … and see if anything looks suspicious to try and prove (or disprove) that the network connection or any of the players in between (firewalls, packet inspectors, you name it) is at fault.